# Error installing json Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems

I'm running `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` however I get this error..

```
gem install json -v '1.8.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170412-72871-wada1h.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                              ^
/Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:795:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) RB_GNUC_EXTENSION_BLOCK(   \
        ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' (aka 'unsigned long (const char *, long)') [-Wint-conversion]
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:840:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                        ^
generator.c:842:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                        ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/johnwilliamson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

When I run just gem install json it installs fine taking me over version 2 however I'm trying to install this https://github.com/peatio/peatio and it wants that version specifically.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just a guess: Since Ruby already has json built-in, I don't think the author of the game expects that only people using a very old Ruby version (1.7, maybe 1.8) to use the Gem, and the native C-interface doesn't work with newer Ruby versions. May I ask why you want to use the Gem, when you have json already in the Ruby standard library?

Comment: I don't want to use the gem myself but it's a depencie in a gem I want to install and I can't find it in the gem file to remove it either :|

Answer (score 1):

Finding and updating the gem that is pulling in the JSON gem should work.  However, another thing that worked for me was to update the version of JSON being installed.

```
bundle update json
```

This worked because it updated JSON to version 1.8.6 which is compatible with newer Rubies.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is arise due to you are not in proper directory. Please go to your rails directory folder first then run this command like this:

```
rails@rails:~/rails_project/btc$ gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

Then its work fine.

Comment: That is not correct. This error has occurred for me within the Rails project directory. It's a dependency resolution error. In my case it was resolved by using a newer version of rails which depended on a different version of json.

Comment: @Kallaste - I am using rails 5.0.7 but I still get this same error (it looks for json 1.8 and I get this error while installing json 1.8). Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: @Biju - Please look at my answer below. Json 1.8 seems to be the problem. I would try using a different version of Rails that does not use json 1.8. I used 4.2.6 myself, so I know that works. You could use an older Rails in the meantime, submit a bug report, and upgrade to the current version when the issue is revolved.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a common issue with the json 1.8.1 gem. You can use a different version of json if you are declaring it explicitly, but in some cases, json 1.8.1 is a cascading dependency. For instance, you may see something like

```
In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
    actionmailer was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
          activesupport was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
            json
```

In this case, you just need to change the top level gem (in this case rails) to a different version. 4.2.6 works.